# How to close a bootstrap modal popup after downloading a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a popup that uses bootstrap modal. The popup allows the user to either download a file or cancel. What I want to do is close the popup once the user clicks on the 'Download' button (and the download starts), as it does for the cancel option.

I tried using data-dismiss on the type submit button for downloading and while that closed it, a download was not initiated.

This is how my two buttons look:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn=secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Right now when I click on the button, a download starts but the popup remains. If I click on Cancel, the popup closes. Can I close after download with something like data-dismiss, or do I need javascript for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript), you can hide your modal with jquery with `$('#myModal').modal('hide')`.
Add an id to your modal and then dismiss it with jquery inside your download function as below:

```
function download() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    ....
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to close the modal using javascript inside the function where you initiate download.  (You can even trigger the clicking of cancel button)

Comment: Would it be window.close or something similar?